# Why X-s restarts after magic Alt+SysRq+REI?

Tags: linux, debian, kernel

Just curiosity:
Which part of my debian is responsble for immediate restart of my X-s after I press Alt+SysRq+REI?
("I have just killed every process - why I have forthcoming "Choose your username" window? I just want to see nothing except kernel or something like it")
If I'll continue pressing UB, disks will not be properly unmounted. (And that's bad, isn't it?).

(It looks little bit similar to my different [SU-question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277125/set-pause-after-usb-ejection?noredirect=1#comment481487_277125), where my operating system is so **proactive** that I cannot detach my usb devices safely and properly)

Answer (score 1):

You have killed every process except init (or systemd, if it replaces init). Init and/or systemd will then try to restart any services that are configured to be running.

On a system using classic rc.d service management, init will only respawn getty processes, allowing login on bare console and not much more.

On a systemd system, systemd will be much more proactive trying to bring the system to an 'up' state if processes die unexpectedly (from systemd's point of view), and thus will also try to restart your graphical user login.